# Yellow jackets freak me out

Tags: riddle, word

> Yellow jackets freak me out
>   Rejection always stings
>   I was brought up
>   Just to fall
>   When will this ever end?

What am I?

Hint 1:

> People are usually busy
>  With some distraction

Hint 2:

> When I come around
>  They tell me to go away
>  But if I stay away too long
>  They start to pray for me

Comment: Is this a "Who Am I" kind of question?

Comment: Yes, it's a "Who Am I" question.

Comment: I prefer rhyming riddles, but I like this riddle a lot. Too bad I can't upvote, for I have reached my daily voting limit (and have to wait $12$ hours before I can upvote again). So, $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> rain

Yellow jackets freak me out
Rejection always stings

> Raincoats keep away the rain, and can be yellow

I was brought up
Just to fall
When will this ever end?

> The water evaporates from the ground, forms clouds, yet inevitably falls back down again.
>  It will end when the expanding Sun swallows us all (so don't worry).

Comment: You are correct :)

Answer (score 3):

New Answer:

> Flower/Fruit; as yellow jackets use to eat them and also they grow and fall one day..

Old Answer:

> Hornets/Yellow jackets or Wasps

reason:

> as they get attracted by yellow color and sting as well

edit:

> I think I misunderstood it. Its opposite to what i am thinking. Will update my answer if I get correct. Sorry;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A building about to be destroyed?

Yellow jackets freak me out

> [This kind](https://it.123rf.com/photo_41681905_architetto-in-giacca-gialla-di-sicurezza-in-posa-con-il-casco-rosso-al-cantiere.html?vti=lnjonzxamwtm7jp94h-1-4) of yellow jackets.

Rejection always stings 
I was brought up 
Just to fall

> It was erected and is about to be demolished.

When will this ever end?

> When all buildings will be destroyed?

Comment: It's kind of in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer is

> "rain".

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please use the spoiler markup >!.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the [Tour]!) Unfortunately, your answer lacks an explanation of why you think it is correct, so may be deleted. Answers should be a thoughtfully considered attempt to solve the puzzle that was posed, with an explanation of how you arrived at the solution and/or why you believe your solution is correct. We're looking for quality answers, not a one-line response containing the first thing that leapt to mind. Please take some time to look around and familiarize yourself with the kinds of answers that are well-received here, ideally before you post any more answers.